# No such configuration property: "sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd"

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kerberos, confluent-platform

I am using librdkafka to write kafka .net client on windows which connects to kafka cluster running in linux OS (basically cross platform). I want to expose all the configurations needed within client and set them with some default values (by default values I want to basically set up simply no encryption and no authentication) so that my end client can change these values as per their security needs.

https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

```
            {"security.protocol", "plaintext" },
            {"ssl.ca.location","" },
            {"sasl.mechanisms","PLAIN" },
            {"sasl.kerberos.service.name","" },
            {"sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd","%{sasl.kerberos.keytab}" },
            {"sasl.kerberos.keytab","" },
            {"sasl.kerberos.principal","" },
```

SSL is working fine when I provide plain text and provide nothing for ca.location. But for SASl, I am getting this exception "No such configuration property: "sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd"". What I am I doing wrong here.

Comment: consider adding more tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, librdkafka only supports GSSAPI/Kerberos through the native windows [SSPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380493(v=vs.85).aspx) - providing authentication using the current logged on user, Windows AD, etc.
The unix kerberos utilities, such as kinit and keytabs, are not supported on Windows.

See the [librdkafka wiki](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka-on-Windows) for more information.

Comment: Just to clarify, essentially these are the needed configurations that I need to expose to my end client at the maximum for them to implement GSSAPI/Kerberos, correct?    
{"sasl.mechanisms","PLAIN" },
{"sasl.kerberos.service.name","" },
{"sasl.kerberos.principal","" },
{"sasl.username",""},
{"sasl.password",""},

Comment: Currently only sasl.mechanisms and sasl.kerberos.service.name will be used on Windows, and the client will try to authenticate as the currently logged on user.

Comment: Gotcha Edenhill. Thanks for the quick reply.